Are questions about alternative coins allowed?
Can we ask and answer questions about Litecoin, Yacoin and other types of altcoins?

related: Should this SE also cover questions about Ripple

Yes, Bitcoin derivatives and other cryptography based currencies such as Ripple are on-topic. 
